# Error on build my app in xcode..shows an symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugin-fcm

when i try to build ios...

xcode shows an error as

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRComponent", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuth.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRComponentType", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuth.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRComponentContainer", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuth.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

this is an ionic project..for ios build through xcode

[image]

Comment: check your framework does only support device , check the framework architecture

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing the Firebase core library.  Make sure you have this in your `Podfile`:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
```

Follow the instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup).

Comment: after updating firebase/core...it shows another some error....ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/angelamal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OurLorry-euszantbpwkshrblueqgfmxppylm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac-Defines-NSData+zlib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/angelamal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OurLorry-euszantbpwkshrblueqgfmxppylm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/nanopb'
ld: library not found for -lGoogleToolboxForMac-Defines-NSData+zlib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: @GokulanathanKN That's a different issue.

Comment: @GokulanathanKN Ask a new question.  Did my answer solve *this* question?  If so mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

> The FIRComponent symbol was introduced in the Firebase 5.5.0 release
>   with a definition in the FirebaseCore pod and reference in the
>   FirebaseAuth pod.
>
> Make sure you have at least version 5.1.0 of the FirebaseCore pod
>   installed.